# Why can't the compiler deduce my template value from the function argument?

Tags: c++, templates, non-type, template-argument-deduction

The following won't compile:

```
enum E {A,B,C};
template<E m> 
void foo(E m) {}

int main() {
    foo(A);
    return 0;
}
```

The errors I get are:

- declaration of 'E m' : void foo(E m) {} : shadows template parm 'E m'
- error: no matching function for call to 'foo(E)' : 
  foo(A);
- candidate is: template void foo(E) : void foo(E m) {}
- template argument deduction/substitution failed: couldn't deduce template parameter 'm' : foo(A);

I don't understand what exactly is wrong here. Why can't the compiler deduce the template parameter from the function argument?

What do I need to do to make this work?

Comment: There's no deduction going on since it's a *non-type* template parameter. All you need is `void foo(E m)`.

Comment: `void foo(E m)` is not a templated fonction.

Comment: No! I do not want to template on type, but on value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want a run-time argument, use:

```
void foo(E m) {}
```

Which has a value `m` of type `E`. (note: no `template<E m>` required)

If you want a compile-time argument, use:

```
template<E m> 
void foo() {}
```

and call:

```
foo<A>();
```

Or if you want `foo` to work for all enumeration types:

```
template<typename E> 
void foo(E m) {}
```

And probably check for enums with

```
static_assert(std::is_enum<E>::value, "E is not an enumeration");
```

in the function body. (You can also use SFINAE to remove `foo` from an overload set if needed, ask if you need help with that)

---

Update: Explaining your original code and what is wrong with it:

```
template<E m> void foo(E m) {}
//       ^^^ (1)       ^^^ (2)
```

(1) is a compile-time argument `m` of type `E`, (2) is a run-time argument *also* called `m` and also of type `E`. Since it has the same name, the second argument hides the first one. Using the name `m` in your function will only access the second argument and you can not access the first one. Now consider:

```
template<E m1> void foo(E m2) {}
```

Now you can access the arguments under different names, i.e., `m1` and `m2`. If you call the function like this:

```
foo<A>(B);
```

then `m1` is `A` and `m2` is `B`. And still both are of the same fixed type `E`. They are independent parameters and the value of the run-time parameter will not be used for the compile-time parameter.

Depending on which kind or argument you need (compile-time or run-time), you simply leave out the one you don't need and you end up with one of the above implementations.

It's not 100% clear to me where your real problem is, which is not untypical for beginners as it is admittedly hard to describe a problem you don't really understand, but make sure you start by understanding the difference between the compile-time and the run-time parameters and how they can be used.

Comment: Thank you. Obviously my actual application is somewhat more complex than this; the enum member determines the return type of the function. I only want it to work with enum type E, but it needs to generate different implementations depending on the enum member used as the argument. My work-around at the moment is to specify the template parameter as you suggested, but I don't understand why I need to do that. How is the function argument hiding the template parameter?

Comment: My problem is simply that I would like to be able to call this function with a function argument and have the compiler deduce that the same value should be used to generate the template, just as you can with template-type parameter deduction. I would like to avoid having to call foo<A>(A) and just call foo(A); the compiler deducing that I require foo<A>(A) because the template value name matches the function argument name. This works perfectly for template-type parameters but I can see no documentation to say this cannot work for template-values.

Comment: @StephenD Your only option is to call `foo<A>()` then - otherwise the return type can never depend on the value of a (non-template) parameter, only on its type.

Comment: Thanks. BTW, I'm not a beginner. I've been writing template code for years and fully understand the difference between compile-time and run-time parameters. Here I am using a compile-time template value, but I cannot find any documentation about this name-hiding problem with template values. It is not a problem when using the value to size an array for example. Perhaps I should re-post this question with a slightly fuller example, and the array-sizing example as a comparison.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you wanted to write:

```
enum E {A,B,C};
template<typename T> 
void foo(T m) {}

int main() {
    foo(A);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No! I want to template on an enum member, not a type.

Answer (score 0):

It has finally dawned on me why this does not compile. Although in my particular case the function argument is a compile-time constant (an enum member), in general a function argument is run-time dependent. The template value must be a compile-time constant, so function argument values are not permissible for template value deduction. If the mechanism for enforcing this is name-hiding, then I think that is incidental.
The conclusion is that whereas templated function types may be deduced from function argument type, template values are not deducible.